# Solve the following inquality

Tags: inequality

> $$|x+1|+|x|>3$$

I have one simple problem. When I break the modulus function, ie. when I get the following expressions

$$-x-1-x$$ $$x+1-x$$ and $$x+1+x$$
When will the inequality corresponding to 3 change? If I don’t change it, I get the wrong answer. If I change it in the first expression, I get the right answer. How do I know when to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the cases $x\geq 0$, $-1\le x<0$ and $x<-1$.
By the hint you will get
$$x+1+x>3$$
$$x+1-x>3$$
$$-x-1-x>3$$
Can you finish now?
Then you will get
$$x>1$$
$$1>3$$ (no solution)
$$-2x>4$$ or $$x<-2$$ (the inequality sign must change!)

Comment: I did that, but I wanna know when would the inequality sign change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are troubled by the fact that when multiplied by a negative  number inequality switches 
$$ -2x>4$$
We multiply both sides by $-1/2$
$$ x<-2 $$